# Android Map set markers to different places

Tags: android, json, notify

I'm new to Android Studio and I was wondering if it is possible to set markers as a programmer in google maps to landmarks and restaurants to notify the user if current location is near one of those markers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question.  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

please use it.
every location you have let,lng

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
       .title("San Francisco");
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)
If you don't mind, can I ask how the application can notify the user if current location is near those markers?

Comment: what is your requirements ?